# AngularJS master checkbox toggler

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible with AngularJs to do: master checkbox which turn on/off it child checkboxes - each one of them showing a different content. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5ox85oik0TC2oPR8zBCm?p=info)`enter code here`

Comment: what do you mean by turn on or off? could you elaborate more on this?

Comment: if master checkbox is on, all 3 divs must me shown/hided

Comment: @user880772 nope, in the example child did not hold ng-show content

Comment: can't use `ng-checked` with `ng-model`. Your expecattions are flawed

Comment: Check at Daniel solution http://plnkr.co/edit/Ma3RFaAmjoJnajlnid5q?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a master checkbox toggle. [Here's a working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ma3RFaAmjoJnajlnid5q?p=preview).

**View**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="checkAll()" />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox[0].selected" />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox[1].selected" />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox[2].selected" />
```

**Controller**

```
// Check/uncheck all boxes
$scope.checkAll = function () {
  angular.forEach($scope.checkbox, function (obj) {
    obj.selected = $scope.selectAll;
  });
};
```

Comment: No at all. Please read carefully and watch my plunker. Every checkbox has different content to show on checked

Comment: @TeodorKolev all you had to do was add in the divs for ng-show. Please check the above plunk again: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ma3RFaAmjoJnajlnid5q?p=preview

Comment: @TeodorKolev If this adequately solved your problem, please mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

add the model to the 'ng-checked' expression

```
  <input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="master || slave1" ng-model="slave1" aria-label="Slave input">
  <input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="master || slave2" ng-model="slave2" aria-label="Slave input">
  <input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="master || slave3" ng-model="slave3" aria-label="Slave input">
```

add 'master' into ng-show expression

```
<div ng-show="slave1 || master">Slave one showed!</div>
<div ng-show="slave2 || master">Slave two showed!</div>
<div ng-show="slave3 || master">Slave three showed!</div>
```

Comment: If http://plnkr.co/edit/5ox85oik0TC2oPR8zBCm?p=preview this is what you mean, there is a problem. Check first one, check master, uncheck master. Result all checkboxes are unchecked BUT first content remain shown. But it shouldn't be

Comment: try to add the model into each 'ng-checked' expression. if you want the check-box to be forced checked/uncheck' when master check-box checked/uncheck, then you probably need to integrate it with ng-click